# TDD in Rails: clarification on Red - Green testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd

Following Michael Hartl's [Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users), I'm unsure how the following validation test is supposed to work:

```
test "name should be present" do
  @user.name = "     "
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

When this test is written, the testing suite should be Red. After adding the corresponding part in the User class as such:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

The test becomes Green. I don't understand how the former part works. Is the test Red because the `validates` part is not implemented yet? After implementing it, `@user.valid?` should be `False` turning into a `True` due to `assert_not`. Thus, the test is Green?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct understanding of it. Before a model in Rails is saved to the database, it must be validated. The test here is checking whether the user model would be considered valid and saved with a blank name. As such, before you add `validates :name, presence: true`, `@user.valid?` evaluates to true and the test fails. Once you add the validation, the model is considered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In a Test driven development (TDD) approach we write test before writing codes. Thus, we make the test fail first and then write some codes to make the test pass.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do have a correct understanding of whats going on.

`assert_not @user.valid?` is saying that the `@user` object is invalid. To start with `@user.name` is set to a blank value; so we expect it the assertion to pass. However, the code is not yet checking for a valid name to be present. So it fails.

Adding `validates :name, presence: true` makes the model check for a valid name to be present. Thus the test passes.